# Is it possible to display file extensions in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

My question is if there is a possibility to display **every**¹ file extensions on https://drive.google.com/.

I didn't find anything in the settings and I personally hate file explorers which are not able to do that. Google itself also didn't find any solutions here.

¹ includes especially Google Docs' own file extensions (*.gdoc* etc.)

Comment: Do you refer to specific files, or in general? Because I can see the extensions for every file that is not part of the Google Docs world

Comment: I mostly have to do with the Google Docs world itself. So I want `document.abc.gdoc` (like in finder) instead of mere  `document.abc`

Comment: I don't think that's possible - but please update your question with this information

Comment: @arieljannai OK I did so

Answer (score 3):

Google Drive is designed to try to make users life simpler which, according to Google, means not dealing with file extensions. However, you can just add them to the end of the file and that won't change the name of the file.

BTW: .gdocs is not really a file extension. It is pretty much just a text file with a link in it to the Google Doc on the web.

Answer (score 2):

Google Drive on the web doesn't include an option to show the file extensions for files that use Google Docs editors formats.

The .gdoc file extensión is not really a Google Document file. It's just a "direct access" (aka "shortcut") file similar to .lnk files. It only include a couple of lines on plain text that tells the computer the URL of the file on Google Drive on the web.

References

- [Shortcut (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing))